# C# - Many to 1 relationship Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, many-to-one

I am trying to map the object from the list with another object which needs to map based on the id.
Please find the below code.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    var config1 = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.CreateMap<Foo, Foo>();

        config.CreateMap<Bar, Foo>();
        config.CreateMap<Bar, Foo>()
              .AfterMap((s, d) => d = s.Foos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == d.Id));
    });

    Foo f = new Foo { Name = "Right", Id = 1 };

    Bar b = new Bar { Foos = new List<Foo>() };
    b.Foos.AddRange(new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Mic", Id = 1 }, new Foo { Name = "John", Id = 2 } });
    IMapper mapper = config1.CreateMapper();

    f = mapper.Map<Foo>(b, a => a.Items[0] = f.Id);
}
```

How to map destination based on destination id match with id present in the list(source)

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: It is not clear what do you try to reach. Does your purpose is to get a first Foo in the list of Foos by id and map it to existing Foo?  Then why do you need to use AutoMapper?

Comment: @GrigoryZhadko, Update the name property of object f as per the id so if i am passing 1 then it should be Mic and if id is 2 then it should be John and may be something wrong in ` f = mapper.Map<Foo>(b, a=>a.Items[0] = f.Id ); `
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Why do you need `bar b` then? You can use a simple list of Foos? I'm just trying to understand your issue, and the bar's code looks useless here.